# Avoiding creation of blank file OR deleting empty file created from xslt ant task

Tags: xslt, ant, delete-file

With xslt transformation using ant it creates a blank file if matching conditions defined in xsl file results in false. Is there a way to avoid creation of blank file when we use http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html ant task?.

If there is no option, is there an easy way to delete blank files created using delete ant task - seems like only size check with filset is supported & not the blank file check.

Sorry for theoretical query. Will post more details tried if needed.

Comment: Ant's [DeleteCharacters filter](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#filterdeletecharacters) can remove whitespace from a file. After the file has been filtered, use `<delete>` on the file.